# URL Shortening using java

Tags: java, performance

I want to use URL shortening service in my project. Where can I find such services and how can I implement these in my code to generate dynamic URL's with shortened length.

I searched for various URL Shortening service on google. I found few popular websites. But unable to find how to implement these in my code.

I want to generate a big URL into smaller by implementing some service in my code basically in java.

Comment: e.g. https://dev.bitly.com/ or https://developer.hootsuite.com/docs/owly-api-reference

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the use of a third party library unless you want to write the code yourself for learning purposes. For example you could use Google's API for creating  goo.gl urls. Find out more about this particular library at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/urlshortener/v1. Depending on exactly what you need, different libraries might be better, so you should do some research. The API is accessed over HTTP, if you have trouble with that then ask a new question or use an existing one.

Comment: Can I use these Google API for an enterprise application for free or is there any licence agreement to use these?

Comment: Not sure, but it is extraordinarily likely that there would be some kind of license agreement (as there is with basically every dependency). Perhaps try reading the documentation?